How to get WinRM setup on a DevTest Lab machine
I would like to provision an Azure DTL Windows Server 2019 Datacenter machine using an ARM template. I have the template for it and it works fine - no problem there. The problem is that I also would like to enable WinRM in it and I am unable to do it. It looks like it's done its thing, but I can't connect to it form my own PC, or from Azure DevOps PowerShellOnTargetMachines task.
I've tried two ways:

Using the WinRM artifact - which is pretty straight forward
Using the Run PowerShell artifact using ConfigureWinRM.ps1, makecert.exe and winrmconf.cmd (as descibed her: https://www.visualstudiogeeks.com/blog/DevOps/Configure-winrm-with-ARM-template-in-AzureDevTestLab-VM-deployment-using-PowerShell-artifact) but with latest/correct GitHub URLs.

Using both ways, it looks like WinRM gets configured, because when I write winrm e winrm/config/listener on the newly provisioned VM, it says both HTTP and HTTPS listeners are enabled, so we know it's running. I also see the HTTPS firewall setting that's set to 'allow'ed (HTTP also FYI).
Is it at all possible to configure WinRM on DTL machines?

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/devtest-labs/create-lab-windows-vm-template.md

Thanks, but this doesn't help.

I realized that in order for WinRM to start working, I will need to at least first sign in to the machine, so it's all set up - meaning the initial sign in is necessary. Is there anyway to overcome that? Ideally, I'd like to be able to automate the whole process.

UPDATE: On further investigation, I discovered it totally depends on this msg that comes up after you boot into a new PC for the first time - "Do you want to allow your PC to be discoverable by other PCs and devices on this network..." - on the right side, on a blue pane. Only when I give it a YES, I am able to Test-WSMan -ComputerName <computer_name>.eastasia.cloudapp.azure.com successfully.
Wow! Is there a way around it? Like, fully automate it if possible?
